# How to add new row to a list using with own class angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

view

> ```
> <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" >
> <td> {{row.ID}} </td>
> <td> {{row.customer}} </td>
> <tr>
> ```
>
> `<button ng-click="quit()">`

controller

```
$scope.rows = [{
        "ID": 12,
        "customer": "abc",            
},{
        "ID": 13,
        "customer": "klm",            
},{
        "ID": 14,
        "customer": "xyz",            
}];
```

I add new row to the list as follow (it works):

```
    Socket.on('delete', function(ID, customer) {

        $scope.rows.push({"ID": ID, "customer": customer});

    }); 

$scope.quit = function() { //code ???? }
```

My purpose is:

(1) each new row should be displayed with colored background (red) and should get an close-button (x) to quit the new row. clicking to this button, the backgroundcolor should reset the backgroundcolor to none and the button should be hide.

(2) 
Which code is needed to quit all new rows with the general button (1 click = reset all red row background to none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem then you need something like 
this:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TuWCf8gpYpMXfuUbsYmz?p=preview

Comment: Adding to this answer you can narrow down search to newly selected ones by using fiters in controllers   $scope.filteredArray = $filter('filter')($scope.rows, { "new": true });
                angular.forEach($scope.filteredArray, function (value, key) {
                    value.new=false;
                });

Comment: Thanks @all. That was my problem, yes. I want to expand this example. How can I do this function vice versa? That means, at first the row(s) which should be deleted have green background and a button to delete it from the list. And again a button to delete ALL. I have prepared it on http://plnkr.co/edit/IFdwkj9F4emi6axhAEX6?p=preview Can you please help me on this, too?

Comment: thanks Oledje. Quit DELETE works. But I cannot delete each row with delete button in the row.

Comment: @ng-User Here the corrected example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nauW15kSNrpymk7fcMeR?p=preview